# Issues with Chrome: Crashing, "Aw Snap", and Flash player crashing

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I'm currently using Google Chrome for Ubuntu 12.04.4. 
My graphics card is an `Nvidia Geforce GT 630`. 
I currently use the Nouveau drivers, since the proprietary drivers seemed buggy. 
Frequently, and especially while loading Flash-based content (but not always), Chrome either crashes (closes completely), freezes (I can use it, but the tab I currently have open doesn't intereact), I get the "Aw Snap" page, or Flash crashes. 
I currently use Chrome's built-in Pepperflash, but Adobe's flash gives me the same issue.

**Here are some terminal logs for crashes:**

```
Recieving an "Aw Snap" page when playing a Flash game:
[WARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED
[2776:2806:0115/222154:ERROR:audio_manager_base.cc(422)] Not implemented reached in virtual std::string media::AudioManagerBase::GetDefaultOutputDeviceID()
[2776:2798:0115/222155:ERROR:audio_manager_base.cc(422)] Not implemented reached in virtual std::string media::AudioManagerBase::GetDefaultOutputDeviceID()
[2776:2798:0115/222159:ERROR:audio_manager_base.cc(422)] Not implemented reached in virtual std::string media::AudioManagerBase::GetDefaultOutputDeviceID()
[2776:2798:0115/222232:ERROR:audio_manager_base.cc(422)] Not implemented reached in virtual std::string media::AudioManagerBase::GetDefaultOutputDeviceID()
[2776:2798:0115/222304:ERROR:audio_manager_base.cc(422)] Not implemented reached in virtual std::string media::AudioManagerBase::GetDefaultOutputDeviceID()
[2776:2798:0115/222306:ERROR:audio_manager_base.cc(422)] Not implemented reached in virtual std::string media::AudioManagerBase::GetDefaultOutputDeviceID()
[2776:2798:0115/222338:ERROR:audio_manager_base.cc(422)] Not implemented reached in virtual std::string media::AudioManagerBase::GetDefaultOutputDeviceID()
--2014-01-15 22:25:15--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 2607:f8b0:4009:805::1002, 173.194.46.35, 173.194.46.36, ...
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|2607:f8b0:4009:805::1002|:443... connected.
--2014-01-15 22:25:15--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 2607:f8b0:4009:800::1004, 173.194.46.105, 173.194.46.98, ...
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|2607:f8b0:4009:800::1004|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `/dev/fd/3'

    [ <=>                                   ] 16          --.-K/s   in 0s      


Crash dump id: 2014-01-15 22:25:15 (2.64 MB/s) - `/dev/fd/3' saved [16]

522ddaaef09bbd7e
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `/dev/fd/3'


    [ <=>                                   ] 16          --.-K/s   in 0s      


Crash dump id: 2014-01-15 22:25:16 (2.77 MB/s) - `/dev/fd/3' saved [16]

6012058ed199d1f8
```

I'll try to update this later with more reports.

Thanks for any help.